# fragment change in Viewpager2 on Button Click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

> 

Can we change fragment in viewpager2 with button click not on tablayout ?
Or there is way make tab layout as button with some corner radius and gap between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by this function -> **setCurrentItem** which takes two parameters the first is the index of fragment that you want, the second is a boolean if you want to change fragment with smooth scroll set it to true:

```
binding.pager.setCurrentItem(1, false)
```